# Can we passe columns dynamically into mysql select statement

Tags: php, mysql

I need to write select statement as we can passe columns in to query dynamically using PHP language.

I have a query like this.

```
SELECT  `Pro_Csharp` +  `Pro_Java` +  `Pro_VBA` +  `Pro_Cplus` +  `Frameworks_Aspdotnet` +  `Fram_MVCdotnet` +  `Fram_WCF` +  `Fram_Hibernate` +  `Fram_Struts` +  `Fram_Spring` +  `Data_transformations_XML` +  `Data_transformations_XSL` AS total_skill
FROM wp_skilllist
ORDER BY total_skill DESC
```

From the interface users can select which subject they want to select.There are about 130 columns. Therefore, I want to handel it dynamically. Is there way to do this?

If we can't do this with mysql and suggestion to this with php language also very helpful.

Comment: you could potentially have it select only 10 columns and return it as a page, the user could go to the next page, and then the database would start from where it left off and return 10 more columns.

Comment: it is ok with printing data, problem is user might select `Pro_java` or not select `Pro_Java`. Then we have to add it or remove it from select statement dynamically.

Comment: @menuwordpress, are you using any checkboxes for the user to select? What are you using on the UI for the user to select these items?

Comment: yes , I use checkbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Build the query string dynamically while parsing the user input:

```
$sqlString = 'SELECT ';
if ($userInput['csharp']) $fields[] = 'Pro_Csharp';
...
$sqlString .= implode (' + ', $fields);
$sqlString .= ' AS total_skill FROM...'; // rest of your query
sendQueryWithDriverOfYourChoice($sqlQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done.

The best way to do this depends on whether you intend to use parameterised statements or not.  As you are new, it would be best to keep it simple.  The following pseudocode gives you an infinitely expandable query.  If you just have a page of checkboxes with names equal to the names of your coloumns, this will work.  Otherwise, you will need to do a bit of cleaning up of the array.

```
$keys=array_keys($_POST);
$sql="SELECT ";
foreach($keys AS $thecolumn)
    {
    $sql.="`$thecolumn`+ ";
    }
$sql=substr($sql,0,strlen($sql)-2); //trim off last +
$sql.=" AS total_skill FROM wp_skilllist ORDER BY total_skill DESC";
```

Comment: Yak's implode method is more elegant than mine!

Comment: Arrgh how??  I thought it was safe - what have I done wrong?  I thought it was safe to use just the post keys, not the content and use this on one of my sites - help!!

Comment: I admit, this is a twisted case, but imagine an attacker forges the following form and posts it to your code: `<form action"page.php"> <input type="text" name="1; DROP TABLE wp_skilllist; SELECT * "></form>`.

Comment: Okay, spaces in ID and NAME are not valid, and PHP seems to replace spaces with underscores. So I might be wrong after all. Sorry for scaring you :)

Comment: Valid point though.  I will escape array keys in future just to be safe.  Thanks.

Comment: I have been able to inject SQL code by replacing spaces with `&nbsp;` in the `name` attribute. You are vulnerable. `<form action="page.php" method="post"> <input type="text" name="1;&nbsp;DROP&nbsp;TABLE&nbsp;wp_skilllist;&nbsp;SELECT&nbsp;*&nbsp;"></form>`